# Getting issue while retrieve location with different location request mode

Tags: location, android-fusedlocation, android-googleapiclient

For retrieve location i have used `GoogleAPIClient` with `FusedLocationProvider` API.

These functions are in `onCreate()` method.

```
 createLocationRequest();
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
 gpsChecker();
```

**Full Code**

```
 protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

public void gpsChecker() {
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(
                                AddVisitActivity.this, 1000);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For run time permissions i did this.

```
  protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
            (AddVisitActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                "Please Grant Permissions",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE",
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(AddVisitActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AddVisitActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION);
                        } else {
                            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, AddVisitActivity.this);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ...: ");
                        }
                    }
                }).show();
    } else {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION);
        } else {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ...: ");
        }
    }

}
```

For checking if the GPS enabled or not in setting screen using *gpsChecker()* with request code *1000* and in *onActivityResult()* i have done this.

```
 if (requestCode == 1000) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Log.i(TAG, "User agreed to make required location settings changes.");
                startLocationUpdates();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Log.i(TAG, "User chose not to make required location settings changes.");
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
```

While i execute this code in some devices its working and in some device the location request automatically set to *Device Only* or *Battery Saving* though i have set `mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);`

**Note :** Mi Note 4, Vivo V9 Pro, Mi Note 5 Pro and some other device getting the issue

So what should i need to change in my code so will it work proper with the High Accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved by changing

```
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

to

```
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

and change

```
private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 60;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
```

interval time to 30 minutes and fastest interval to 5 seconds means once get location in 5 seconds after then new location will be get in 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solutin with GPS Provider and make sure that your GPS service is ON.

static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
    static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

//put this in onCreate();
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

```
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    mprovider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    if (mprovider != null && !mprovider.equals("")) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mprovider);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mprovider, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE, this);

        if (location != null)
            onLocationChanged(location);
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location Provider Found Check Your Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //put this LocationListener after onCreate();
    public LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            Log.e(String.format("%f, %f", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), "");
            Log.e("Location available", "Location available");
            locationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
        } else {
            Log.e("Location is null", "Location is null");
        }

        current_latitude = location.getLatitude();
        current_longitude = location.getLongitude();

       /* LatLng latLng = new LatLng(current_latitude, current_longitude);
        points.add(latLng);
        redrawLine();*/

        Log.e("current_latitude", String.valueOf(current_latitude));
        Log.e("current_longitude", String.valueOf(current_longitude));

        if (location.hasSpeed()) {
            //progressBarCircularIndeterminate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            String speed = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.0f", location.getSpeed() * 3.6) + "km/h";

            SpannableString s = new SpannableString(speed);
            s.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.25f), s.length() - 4, s.length(), 0);
            txt_current_speed.setText(s);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but my issue was location mode.